# CSS: How to automatically resize a circular image as a window resizes?

Tags: image, css, responsive-design, adaptive-design

I'm using this CSS to create a circular image 220px wide, centered within its container (a 3-column span of an 1180px grid):

```
.circular-image {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;

  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border-radius: 110px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 110px;
  background: url(images/some-image.png);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

And I know that you can cause images to automatically rescale using:

```
img {
  height: auto;
}
```

How do I do this for circular images?

Comment: You should always put the unprefixed property after the prefixed ones. Also, both unprefixed `border-radius` and unprefixed `box-shadow` have excellent support these days (see caniuse.com), which means that you could even drop prefixes completely if you don't need to support FF3.6 or old Android versions.

Comment: only give your images a flexible width -ie- percentage, height is already auto. All set

Answer (score 1):

What is the exact problem with circular images? If you have problems with the "roundness" of the image you should change the `border-radius` property to a relative value:

```
.circular-image {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;

    width: 75%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jGCqV/1/).

Comment: This will not work if the image is not a square, if the image is rectangle then with your css it is becoming oval shape

Answer (score 0):

`border-radius: 50%;` will make an element round for what ever size it is (so long as the width and height are the same).

Comment: This won't render properly in some versions of older Android and Blackberry. Use a high px or em value (999em) to get the best browser support.